# JQuery: Select Option from DropDownList given value of adjacent cell in table

Tags: jquery

I am creating a survey that is conducted each year.  To make it fast, i want to have a button that will automatically select the answer in a dropdownlist from the previous year's survey (this answer is available as a span in a preceding cell (same row) in a table). Because this table can be hundreds of rows, i can't use specific id/name selectors.  What i am trying to do is store the span located before the hyperlink in a variable, and then use that to select an option in the cell following the hyperlink

**Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $("[id$='lbCopy']").click(
            function () {
                var $prevReason = $(this).parent().prev().children().text();
                $(this).parent().next().children('select > option:contains("' + $prevReason + '")').prop("selected", true); 
            })
     });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<td>
    <span id="ctl00_body_gvBacklog_ctl02_lblPrevYearReason">Recalcitrant RP</span>
</td>
<td>
    <a id="ctl00_body_gvBacklog_ctl02_lbCopy">Copy</a>
</td>
<td>
    <select name="ctl00$body$gvBacklog$ctl02$ddlReasonNotClosed" id="ctl00_body_gvBacklog_ctl02_ddlReasonNotClosed">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Contamination Above Standards">Contamination Above Standards</option>
        <option value="Recalcitrant RP">Recalcitrant RP</option>
        <option value="Remediation Ongoing">Remediation Ongoing</option>
        <option value="SMAC Eligible">SMAC Eligible</option>
        <option value="SMAC Eligible w/MW Closure">SMAC Eligible w/MW Closure</option>
        <option value="SMAC Eligible w/Notice">SMAC Eligible w/Notice</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

For whatever reason this does not work. I get no errors, but the dropdownlist does not get modified. I know my selector is solid, because i can use it to change the option of all dropdowns, just not the adjacent dropdown.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should we assume your script is located after the select on the page?

Comment: Script is located in the <head> section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children` only selects elements one level down, you're trying to select descendants so use `find` instead.

```
$(this).parent().next().find('select > option:contains("' + $prevReason + '")').prop("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with the HTML code of your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehrGk/

```
$(function () {
    $("[id$='lbCopy']").click(

    function () {
        var $prevReason = $(this).prev().text();
        $(this).next().find('option:contains("' + $prevReason + '")').prop("selected", true);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, as for me, I'll try to avoid having variable inside the selector

```
  $(function () {
         $("[id$='lbCopy']").click(
            function () {
                var $prevReason = $(this).parent().prev().children().text();

                $(this).parent().next().find('option').filter(function(){ 
                    return $(this).html() == $prevReason; 
                }).prop("selected", true); 

            })
     });
```